# Trying to send email using outlook credentials in python

Tags: python, authentication, email, office365, smtp-auth

```
outlook_server = 'smtp-mail.outlook.com'
outlook_port = 587

# Your email credentials
username = ''
password = ''
# password = 'Alpine1400!'
# Create a connection to the SMTP server using SSL
server = smtplib.SMTP(outlook_server, outlook_port)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.ehlo()
server.ehlo()
# Log in to your account
server.login(username, password, initial_response_ok=True)
```

i have attached the error image
i m getting this error on server.login line
checked the credentials numerous times and i m using app password generated by outlook
have tried all the ports my firewall is also off no antivirus running meaning i have exhausted all the google chatgpt solutions still having the same error if anyone can help here

ERROR:

smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [DX0P273CA0065.AREP273.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM 2023-11-17T14:12:55.892Z 08DBE70BA75BEAD0]')

Comment: You haven't attached any error

Comment: attached the error line

Answer (score 0):

Office 365 no longer allows basic credentials when sending messages through SMTP. You need to use OAuth.

Comment: how to use OAuth ?
can you share an example code?

Comment: see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/authenticated-client-smtp-submission